# What's the "best" way to add an ip route using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am unable to find an ansible module that adds ip routes.

Basically the command I'm looking for should allow something like:

```
sudo ip route add 12.3.4.0/24 via 123.456.78.90
```

I found [net_static_route_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/net_static_route_module.html) which seems related, but is deprecated since 2022-06-01.

A simple solution would be:

```
- name: Add a route
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: sudo ip route add 12.3.4.0/24 via 123.456.78.90
```

of course, but inbuilt modules are usually better.

**Additional information**

This task will be executed on a subset of all nodes (ubuntu 22.04 machines that are all part of a cloud cluster using openstack) (specified by groups). Concrete subnets and IPs will be defined using variables.

An example hostfile could look like this:

```
master:
  hosts:
    localhost:
      ansible_connection: local
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      ansible_user: ubuntu
      ip: localhost
workers:
  children:
    ephemeral:
      hosts: {}
  hosts:
    someworker:
      ansible_connection: ssh
      ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
      ansible_user: ubuntu
```

This playbook will be used to setup wireguard. Every vpn-node (those nodes will be connected with each other via wireguard) is connected in its own subnet with multiple worker nodes. Those workers need to add the ip route to get back to the master node which is in a different subnet, but in the same virtual subnet created by wireguard and the vpn nodes). I do not think that this is related to my question, but I might overlook how this can affect the right answer.

Comment: "_I was unable to find it inside the maintained Ansible documentation._" because of [`net_static_route` module – (deprecated, removed after 2022-06-01) Manage static IP routes on network appliances (routers, switches et. al.)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/ansible/netcommon/net_static_route_module.html).

Comment: In the current state your question looks like you are looking for something only and seems to be off-topic therefore. Can you edit your question and provide more details and descriptions about your infrastructure? Especially about your Remote Nodes, respective targets, where do you like to add.

Comment: @U880D I added some information and rephrased the question.

Comment: There is still no description about your Remote Nodes or targets.

Comment: What kind of description would you think might be helpful? In the mean time I will add a bit more, but I fail to see what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description I understand that you like to configure the network route settings on a Linux based operating system (Debian/GNU Linux, Ubuntu 22.04) and not on a dedicated router or switch.

Whereby the mentioned module [`net_static_route`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/ansible/netcommon/net_static_route_module.html) was for providing

> *... declarative management of static IP routes on network appliances (routers, switches et. al.).*

and became deprecated

> ***Removed in:** major release after 2022-06-01*
> ***Why:** Updated modules released with more functionality*
> ***Alternative:** Use platform-specific `[netos]_static_route` module*

it further recommends to use the vendor and platform specific modules instead.

Certain Linux Distributions tend to integrate and use [NetworkManager](https://opensource.com/article/22/4/networkmanager-linux) for creating and managing network connections.

**Documentation**

- [RHEL7 - Getting Started with NetworkManager](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/getting_started_with_networkmanager)
- [ArchLinux - NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager)
- [Ubuntu - NetworkManager](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager)
- ...

So the respective Ansible module for this is [`nmcli` module – Manage Networking](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html). You may have a look into the [Parameters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html#parameters) and [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html#examples), especially into the parameters for `route*`.

**Further Readings**

For more examples have a look at

- [How to configure network settings with Ansible system roles](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/configure-network-ansible-roles)
- [Linux System Roles](https://linux-system-roles.github.io/)